# jQuery UI autocomplete on change event not firing real time

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Using jQuery UI, I am trying to fire an event as soon as the value of the `#tag` input changed but as you can see the `log` event fires if user clicks on the page and not as soon as the value of the input changes

I already tried to bind the change event with `paste` but I am getting the same result.

```js
 $( function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
    
     $("#tags").on('change', function(){
        console.log($(this).val());
    });
  } );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell the Javascript is performing as expected. The `Change` event only fires after the Inputs value has changed. Change does not necessarily mean the instant the value changes. Change means when the value of the input has been committed to a different value. If you want something to happen every time an action is made then use the input event.

```js
$( function() {
        var availableTags = [
          "ActionScript",
          "AppleScript",
          "Asp",
          "BASIC",
          "C",
          "C++",
          "Clojure",
          "COBOL",
          "ColdFusion",
          "Erlang",
          "Fortran",
          "Groovy",
          "Haskell",
          "Java",
          "JavaScript",
          "Lisp",
          "Perl",
          "PHP",
          "Python",
          "Ruby",
          "Scala",
          "Scheme"
        ];
        $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
          source: availableTags
        });
        
         $("#tags").on('input', function(){
            console.log($(this).val());
        });
      } );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<label>Input:</label>
<input type='text' value='' id='tags'/>
```

Comment: Nice.  Learn something new every day - had never heard of `input` event before your answer!

Comment: I prefer the `input` event because it fires when the input actually changes. Think of it like the `change` event but actually working the way you expected it to. The `keyup` event can fire when any key is let up while whatever it is has focus.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you actually want, but you can use [`keypress`](https://api.jquery.com/keypress/) or [`keydown`](https://api.jquery.com/keydown/) instead of `change` and the code will fire whenever the user writes in the input.

```
$("#tags").on('keypress', function(){
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Per jQuery docs: **Note: as the keypress event isn't covered by any official specification, the actual behavior encountered when using it may differ across browsers, browser versions, and platforms.** - I have found the only way to get true cross-browser consistency is to use `keyup` (not even `keydown`).